# Effectively getting count of whos here on discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a command for my discord bot that allows people to check in within a time frame and get a count of who's here, regardless of the max amount of people present. Currently I have this:

```
case "report":

    const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('here');

    message.channel.sendMessage("Report your accountability!");
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { 
        max: 200,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ['time'] 
    })
    .then(collected => {
        message.channel.sendMessage(`Accountability is ${collected.size} of ${message.guild.members.size}, present or accounted for.`);
    });
    break;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what the problem seems to be, since the code gets to the first sendMessage and seems like it's working through my test channel. Thanks so much for any clarification on concepts!

Comment: `#sendMessage();` is deprecated. Use `#send();` instead. As for your issue, I can't help as I don't know what `m` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're dealing with, is you're expecting `.then` to be called once the time is up. In reality, hitting the time limit is considered an "error" - as seen in the [`.awaitMessages` Example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages):

```
...
// Errors: ['time'] treats ending because of the time limit as an error
channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 4, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => console.log(collected.size))
    .catch(collected => console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 voted.`));
```

So, for your code to work as you'd like, you just need to use the `.catch` statement after your `channel.awaitMessages` call, like this:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { 
    max: 200,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time'] 
})
.then(collected => {
    message.channel.send(`Accountability is ${collected.size} of ${message.guild.members.size}, present or accounted for.`);
})
// .catch is called on error - time up is considered an error (says so in docs)
.catch(collected => {
    message.channel.send(`Accountability is ${collected.size} of ${message.guild.members.size}, present or accounted for.`);
});
```

**Note:** As mentioned by @Splinxyy in the comments, you should use `.send` instead of the deprecated `.sendMessage` function.

**Edit:** In the comments you expressed you may want to only count the unique users who send `'here'` in the channel. One method of doing this would be to store user ids in an array, and check the user id hasn't been counted yet, via the filter array:

```
let uidHolder = [];
const filter = m => {
    let id = m.author.id;
    if (uidHolder.includes(id) || !m.content.startsWith('here'))
        return false;
    else {
        uidHolder.push(id);
        return true;
    }
};
```

If you don't like this method, you should be able to muck around with the `collected` variable returned from `.then` / `.catch`. But using the `filter` function may be easier.

Comment: Thank you! So far it works well, this should differentiate between whether I say it or someone else says it, right? I had that problem with another implementation of it I tried

Comment: You mean saying "here"? No... I think this will count you multiple times if you send "here" multiple times... You want it to count unique people saying "here" probably, right?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, however it's not the worst thing if thats not possible.

Comment: @AndresSepulveda - check out my edit. Hopefully this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much @blundering philosopher! This method definitely is working now. I don't mean to keep asking like a help vampire, but those user IDs can be accessed later after the fact, correct?

Comment: @AndresSepulveda - Haha no worries! Yes, you should be able to access them in the `.then` and `.catch` promise methods, but they may not be available much after that - like once you get out of that `case "report":` scope, the variable will be toast. If you need it later, you can declare it elsewhere or return it, or do other fancy things :D